# PHP change content with <select>

Tags: php, select

I have select menu and I want to change content when I change values like jquery but with php. I find this in answers but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$page = null;
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
$page = $_POST['page'];
}
switch($page){
case 'page3': include_once('/path/to/page3content.php'); break;
case 'page2': include_once('/path/to/page2content.php'); break;
case 'page1': include_once('/path/to/page1content.php'); break;
default: include_once('/path/to/defaultcontent.php'); break;
}
?>
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
<select name="page" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="page1"<?php if($page == "page1"){ echo " selected"; }?>>Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2"<?php if($page == "page2"){ echo " selected";}?>>Page 2</option>
    <option value="page3"<?php if($page == "page3"){ echo " selected";}?>>Page 3</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: The problem was in my browser. Now content is show before my form I want content to show after `</select>` How to do this?

Comment: What error are you getting? what is it doing that makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I have no errors. When I click page 2 or page 3 content is not change.

Comment: I would make sure that you have `display_errors` and `error_reporting` turned on firstly. Secondly, are the paths to your files correct?

Comment: for the attribute selected it looks like this selected="selected"

Comment: There's nothing fatally wrong with that script - check that the files you're attempting to `include` actually exist.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Does the page reload? You are seeing `defaultcontent.php` every load? @PedroLobito There aren't PHP errors, `When I click page 2 or page 3 content is not change.`

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem was in my browser. With this code content show in above. How to do content to show after </select>?

Comment: Move the `switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show content after select then update this code

```
 <?php
session_start();
$page = null;
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $_SESSION['page'] = $page;
} else {
    $page = $_SESSION['page'];
}

?>
    <form name="myform" action="" method="post">
        <select name="page" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="page1"<?php if ($page == "page1") {
                echo " selected";
            } ?>>Page 1
            </option>
            <option value="page2"<?php if ($page == "page2") {
                echo " selected";
            } ?>>Page 2
            </option>
            <option value="page3"<?php if ($page == "page3") {
                echo " selected";
            } ?>>Page 3
            </option>
        </select>
    </form>

<?php
switch ($page) {
    case 'page3':
        include_once('/path/to/page3content.php');
        break;
    case 'page2':
        include_once('/path/to/page2content.php');
        break;
    case 'page1':
        include_once('/path/to/page1content.php');
        break;
    default:
        include_once('/path/to/defaultcontent.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: please check now

Comment: Not reload again.

Comment: please check now

Comment: Same. Not reload

Comment: form end tag was missing so try again and reload not work i am not clear

Comment: When I select page 2, or page 3 do nothing. Stay on default.